# Запуск AndroidApplication (LibGDX) из Activity

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-intent, genymotion

Создал игрушку на LibGDX. Решил добавить стартовый экран, с разными настройками. 
Стартовый экран, это Activity которое загружает Layout с кнопкой "Старт".
При нажатии кнопки вызываю:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

AndroidLauncher это AndroidApplication из LibGDX.

На моем SGS4 (Android 4.4.2) это работает. А на Genymotion c образом "Google Nexus 10 Android 5.0.0" после нажатия кнопки старт - черный экран, и никакой реакции. Эмулятор тупо виснет, только закрывать. При этом, если не использовать стартовое меню, а сразу прописать в манифесте AndroidLauncher как MAIN то всё работает, но естественно без стартового меню.
На Genymotion с другими образами, например "Nexus 7 Android 4.2.2", или даже "Custom Phone Android 5.0.0" всё работает.

Куда копать?